# Meaning of the phrasal verb "get in" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/F7flSW1PGsA). It is at around 8 minute and 6 second.

> So it is not going to be Woodrow Wilson because it would be obvious, but I don't the names of any other prominent democrats, so I am going to guess Woodrow Wilson. Yes? **Get in**!

I have checked all the meanings the phrasal verb has in a [dictionary](https://www.google.com.ua/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/get-in), but still I am struggling to understand what the host means by that.

Comment: I have no idea what it means, from what you have posted above. I haven't listened to the clip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This presenter is chock full of phrases from 20th century American popular culture.  When a contestant on an American TV game show won a new car, the show's emcee would shout, "Get in!".

Here, he has just given a correct answer, and is imagining himself to be the emcee telling him that he has "won" the prize.  He's alluding to such a game show. There are even little bells ringing, a faint echo of the blaring horns and flashing lights, rings and gongs that would signal success in those 20th century TV game shows.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Urban Dictionary may not be a good reference, but based on his reaction and the situation in which this phrase is said, it seems to be **an expression of success or celebration** and I think its meaning is close to this definition from Urban Dictionary:

**[Get in](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Get%20in)** (*interjection*, Chiefly British):

> Expression of victory or happiness of the result of a given situation.